# Simulating a raised cosine filter

Tags: matlab, filters, digital-communications, c, reference-implementation

I am rewriting a simulation written in Matlab to C. I have a problem with a transmit data. The data is filtered by a raised cosine filter. In Matlab it was implemented by using the following function [firrcos](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/toolbox/signal/firrcos.html):

```
h = firrcos(20,0.25,0.25);
```

Does anyone know how I can find the documentation of this function ( matlab code realisation)?
Does anyone have a simualtion such filter in Matlab or in C?

**EDIT1**

Given the order of the filter N=20, carrier frequency Fc=0,25, transition band tbW=0,25 and sampling frequency 8.

I need to initialise such filter in  Simulink.

how to determine a filter span and rolloff factor knowing only the parameters above?

**EDIT2**

Why the filter impulse response of the filter in Simulink does look different as its implementation in Matlab?

In matlab the upper limit is 0, in Simulink it is 10

**EDIT 3**

How to initialise h = firrcos(20,0.25,0.25); in simulink?

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB's documentation doesn't recommend the use of `firrcos`, instead use [rcosdesign](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/rcosdesign.html) as recommend. Type `doc firrcos`  in your command window, here are the first lines:

> `firrcos` Raised Cosine FIR Filter design.
>
> WARNING: `firrcos` is not recommended. Use `RCOSDESIGN` instead.

My guess is that `firrcos` is actually discontinued in new releases. To better help you, try using `rcosdesign` as recommended. You can actually get the actual MATLAB code for this function by typing the following lines in your MATLAB's command window: `edit rcosdesign` (you can also check `edit firrcos`). This opens a new editor window with the actual code for the function. This can help you.

Note that in your **EDIT1**, `Fc` is actually the cutoff (not carrier) frequency if you double-check the documentation, and that with three input arguments as you have the default $F_s = 2$. The roll-off factor is a measure of the excess bandwidth expressed as a fraction. The span of the filter in symbols is for you to define.

To add to what has been mentioned by @MBaz, what you need at the transmitter is the [root-raised cosine filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-raised-cosine_filter). This is so that at the receiver side you also put a  root-raised cosine and the two together result in a [raised-cosine filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised-cosine_filter) which is a Nyquist filter with zero [ISI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersymbol_interference) while the root-raised cosine doesn't exhibit zeros (in amplitude) at symbol times.

**EDIT:**

To see the equivalence between the two functions you'll have to give the correct input parameters to both functions. As discussed, first things is having a root-raised cosine. You can do this by setting the 6th and 4th input of `firrcos` and `rcosdesign` respectively to `sqrt`. The equivalents of the remaining parameters are as follows:

```
beta = R;
sps = Fs/(2*Fc);
span = N / sps;
```

Then you have the unnormalized two filters as:

```
h1 = firrcos(N, Fc, R, Fs, 'rolloff', 'sqrt');
h2 = rcosdesign(R, N/(Fs/Fc/2), Fs/Fc/2, 'sqrt');
```

More on this together with the needed normalization can be found in MATLAB's [Communications Toolbox™ Release Notes for R2020b](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/comm/rn.pdf) under the chapter on R2013b (I guess it got discontinued after then) titled *Functionality Being Changed or Removed*.

For your Simulink, click on *Simulink Library Browser* then on the list on your left choose *Communications Toolbox* then pick *Comm Filters*. There you have all your filters, you can set the chosen raised-cosine filter as discussed up.

Comment: how to rewrite firrcos(20,0.25,0.25); to rcosdesign?

Comment: @Ali23, please see the edit in my answer above.

Comment: @Ali23, if this has answered your question remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The raised-cosine filter impulse response is documented in many textbooks and in Wikpedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised-cosine_filter). All you need to do is implement that impulse response in your C program.

If you are transmitting data, you should really be using a root raised-cosine filter (raised cosine pulses are not orthogonal). Their impulse response is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-raised-cosine_filter).

Comment: will be it enough for simulation it in hardware (FPGA)?

Comment: What do you mean by "enough"?